# Codeception: using REST module on TEST

Tags: unit-testing, laravel-5.1, codeception

**I have this code in \tests\unit\ReportTest.php** :

```
class ReportTest extends \Codeception\TestCase\Test
{

    protected function _before()
    {
        Auth::attempt(['email' => $this->valid_email, 'password' => $this->valid_password]);
    }

    protected function _after()
    {
    }

    public function testMe()
    {
        $this->sendGet(route('index'));
        $this->canSeeResponseCodeIs(200);
    }
}
```

My problem is that the methods `$this->sendGet()` and `$this->canSeeResponseCodeIs()` are undefined, I'm kind of new on using Codeception so bear with me guys,

here is my `unit.suite.yml`:

```
class_name: UnitTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Asserts
        - \Helper\Unit
        - Laravel5
        - REST:
            depends: PhpBrowser
    config:
      Laravel5:
        environment_file: .env
```

I want to use the REST module, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems its better to use CEST when using REST module than using TEST.